# Error : "createSliderWithTooltip is not a function"

Tags: reactjs, rc-slider

Im trying to implement the rc-slider for the web app however the rc-slider tooltip isnt recognized and shows an error of **"createSliderWithTooltip is not a function"** , which im not sure why .

For implementation of rc-slider i followed the rc-slider documentation which is the same way i have implemeneted in the code of home.js somehow im getting an error in console and nothing shows at all.

Thanks in advance.

```
Home.js 
import React, { Fragment, useEffect , useState } from 'react'
import MetaData from './layouts/MetaData'
import { useDispatch , useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { getProducts } from '../actions/products'
import Product from './products/Products'
import Loader from './layouts/Loader'
import { useAlert } from 'react-alert'
import Pagination from "react-js-pagination";
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom'

import Slider from 'rc-slider'
import 'rc-slider/assets/index.css';

const { createSliderWithTooltip } = Slider;**//Error occurs here**
const Range = createSliderWithTooltip(Slider.Range) 

const Home = () => {
  

  const [currentPage,setCurrentPage]=useState(1);
  const [price,setPrice]=useState([1,1000]);
  let params=useParams();
  const dispatch= useDispatch();
  const alert=useAlert();
  const {loading,products,error,productsCount,resPerPage,filteredProductsCount }= useSelector(state=>state.products)
  const keyword=params.keyword;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) {
      return alert.error("error");
    }
    dispatch(getProducts(keyword, currentPage));
 }, [dispatch, alert, error, currentPage, keyword]);
  
  function setCurrentPageNo(pageNumber) {
    setCurrentPage(pageNumber)
}

  return (
    <Fragment>
    {loading ? <Loader>Loading ...</Loader>:(
    <Fragment>
    <MetaData title={'Buy Electronics , Household Items and Many Others Online'} />
    <h1 id="products_heading">Latest Products</h1>
    <section id="products" className="container mt-5">
      <div className="row">
       
      <Fragment>
                                    <div className="col-6 col-md-3 mt-5 mb-5">
                                        <div className="px-5">
                                            <Range
                                                marks={{
                                                    1: `$1`,
                                                    1000: `$1000`
                                                }}
                                                min={1}
                                                max={1000}
                                                defaultValue={[1, 1000]}
                                                tipFormatter={value => `$${value}`}
                                                tipProps={{
                                                    placement: "top",
                                                    visible: true
                                                }}
                                                value={price}
                                                onChange={price => setPrice(price)}
                                            />
                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                            </Fragment>
   
      {products.map(product => (
      <Product key={product._id} product={product} col={4} />
      ))}   
      </div>
      </section>
      <div className="d-flex justify-content-center mt-5">
                            <Pagination
                                activePage={currentPage}
                                itemsCountPerPage={resPerPage}
                                totalItemsCount={productsCount}
                                onChange={setCurrentPageNo}//sets current page no as it changes for state management
                                nextPageText={'Next'}
                                prevPageText={'Prev'}
                                
                                itemClass="page-item"
                                linkClass="page-link"
                            />
                        </div>
                    
    </Fragment>
    
    
  )
}
</Fragment>
)}
export default Home
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `const { createSliderWithTooltip } = Slider;`, try this:

```
const createSliderWithTooltip = Slider.createSliderWithTooltip;
```

Comment: Same error follows : "createSliderWithTooltip is not a function"

Answer (score 2):

I tried several ways and the only thing that actually worked was downgrading to 9.6.5 rc-slider and now everything is working perfectly

Answer (score 2):

The document hasn't been updated yet since new version. As it seems you want to use Range component, now here the way to do it (thanks to Ashvin-Pal): https://github.com/react-component/slider/issues/825#issuecomment-1084416952

Answer (score 1):

The `createSliderWithTooltip` has been removed in the new version.
Instead, you can implement your custom handle or tooltip easily like this:

```
handleRender={renderProps => {
                        return (
                            <div {...renderProps.props}>
                                <SliderTooltip>{round}%</SliderTooltip>
                            </div>
                        );
                    }}
```

let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: This worked for me with rc-slider 10.1.1. Note for others: handleRender is a prop on Slider.

Comment: @Chrkik Can you help me with a full example on how to use this? 
Not sure I understand. I'm using a Slider right now and want to add a sliderTooltip

Answer (score 0):

As mention in the [discussion](https://github.com/react-component/slider/issues/825#issuecomment-1084416952), in version>10 this function isn't support anymore.

I have found a way to draw it with the `handleRender` argument (Inspired by @Cherik's answer)

In a separate `SliderTooltip.tsx` file write the following code"

```js
interface SliderTooltipProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  theme: any;
}

const SliderTooltip: React.FC<SliderTooltipProps> = ({ children, theme={} }) => {
    
    const themeTooltip = {
        ...theme,
        color: theme.color || "red",
        fontSize: theme.fontSize || "14px",
        fontFamily: theme.fontFamily || "Source Sans Pro, mono",
        whiteSpace: theme.whiteSpace || "nowrap",
        position: "relative",
        bottom: "100%",
        transform: "translate(-50%, -10px)",
      }
  

  return (
    <div style={themeTooltip}>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

export default SliderTooltip;
```

and in your code where you want to add the slider:

```js
import Slider from "rc-slider";
import SliderTooltip from "./SliderTooltip";

... rest of your code 

<Slider
        handleRender={(renderProps) => {
          return (
            <div {...renderProps.props}>
              <SliderTooltip theme={theme}>{value}</SliderTooltip>
            </div>
          );
        }}
      />
```