# Tooltip in rc-slider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slider, tooltip

I need to add a Tooltip to the slider
In React

I try to add according to the site but without success.

I use this package

https://slider-react-component.vercel.app/

```
const Slider = require('rc-slider');
const createSliderWithTooltip = Slider.createSliderWithTooltip;
const Range = createSliderWithTooltip(Slider.Range);
```

Anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: I answered this before, Please check it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73538271/8808612